# using ng-route in angular to route to different htmls using the routeconfig param

Tags: angularjs

i new to angular routing. I have an index.html and home.html. what i am trying to do is by default the index.html should be loaded.There is a link from index.html to home.html. How would i load the index file with a default url using route like 
http://localhost/myapp?user=123.

I have deployed my codebase in IIS with virtual directory as myapp.

Also when i click on the home link the url should change to

http://localhost/myapp/index.html#/home

What i am trying to do is:

**app.js**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl:'index.html', controller: 'MainController'});
            $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl:'home.html',controller: 'TestController'});
            $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
            }]);
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController as main">
        <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
    </div>
```

**Controller.js**

```
app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$log','$location', function($scope,$log,$location) {

    $log.info("Test Controller loaded");

    test();
    $scope.test = function(){
        console.log("Test");
    }

    $log.info("Test Controller function");

}])
```

Both the controllers are not getting loaded. The main controller is similar to test controller. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment as I don't have enough reputation, but do you have the `ng-app` directive somewhere in your code ? Like `ng-app="myApp"` in a body/html tag or something like that ? Plus, if you're using angular routes, you shouldn't need the `ng-controller` directive in your `index.html` file as your controller will be set by your routeProvider.

---

Edit : I think it's a problem with your tags or the structure of your code.

- You might have an `index.html` with the `ng-app` directive AND an `ng-view`
- Your `index.html` content should be in another html file (like my `nav.html` in the plunker below)

That's the only thing I had to do in order to get your code working.

You can look at this plunker, which reuses mostly your code : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/DbgJKe51c7QoGCG6rXlN?p=info

Comment: yes i have ng-app directive bound to the html tag. Also the controller wasnot getting bound through routeconfig, hence i bound in the div section of the html file.